# Grails 4 bootstrap not running

Tags: grails

Hi I just installed Grails 4, created some domain classes. I added the following code to BootStrap to populate a Table:

```
 def init = { servletContext ->

        println ("================ in bootstrap ===============")

        def mentor = new Mentor(username:"cnm",password:"password", fin:"ext")

        try {
            mentor.save()
            println ("mentor ok")

        } catch(Exception e) {
            println ("error :$e")
        }

    }
```

But is not run. Tried with the debugger and didn't reach the breakpoint either. Is there a new config option in version 4 to run it?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why doesn't stop but in gr4 you will need a transaction to save your domain objects

Comment: Have you seen your "println" messages into a console?

Comment: No. They don't tried with slf4j too and nothing

Comment: Recreated the project with grails 3 and at least runs the code aforementioned

Comment: I created the simpliest project with grails 4.0.1 + jdk 1.8.0_221, added Domain class Mentor, copied your boostrap code to mine and *saw your println messages*. Please, provide your example via github or I can share what I've done

Comment: Thanks it worked after I assigned the roles. Thanks

Comment: There are a number of reasons that the code you show may not yield the behavior you expect but you haven't provided enough information to know why `BootStrap` isn't even running. See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/xainbootstrap. https://github.com/jeffbrown/xainbootstrap/blob/master/grails-app/init/xainbootstrap/BootStrap.groovy runs as expected.